# What's the difference between childObj.prototype = Object.create(parentObj.prototype) and childObj.prototype = parentObj.prototype?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, prototype-programming

I'd like to know the difference between:

```
childObj.prototype = Object.create(parentObj.prototype)
```

and

```
childObj.prototype = parentObj.prototype;
```

Because both of them I need to call the parent constructor inside the child object to have access to the constructor properties.

I know how Object.create function works, and I notice that the difference is only because It returns a NEW object with the with the parent's prototype. I guess what I'm not understanding is the effect of returning a new object with the parent's prototype.

Comment: the first sets up a prototype chain, where you can modify child.prototype after and it won't affect the parent. The second is literally aliasing the two to point to the same data structure, and modifications through either modify that single data structure, affecting both. You want the first, although usually you want `ChildObj.prototype = new ParentObj()` instead of needing Object.create

Comment: *although usually you want `ChildObj.prototype = new ParentObj()`* Probably not, as this calls the `ParentObj` constructor while assigning the `.prototype` to its child, NOT when a new instance is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first sample is the correct way to go about it, as it creates a new object with the `parentObj.prototype` as its `[[Prototype]]`:

```
childObj.prototype = Object.create(parentObj.prototype); // { __proto__: parentObj.prototype }
```

The second one just sets `childObj.prototype` to the same object as the `parentObj.prototype`. This causes some problems:

```
function parentObj() {
}

parentObj.prototype.parentFn = function() { console.log('parent'); };


function childObj() {
}

childObj.prototype = parentObj.prototype;

// here we are writing onto parentObj.prototype as well!!!
childObj.prototype.childFn = function() { console.log('child'); };

var child = new childObj();

var parent = new childObj();

child.parentFn(); // 'parent'
parent.childFn(); // 'child' --- this should not happen!!!
```

In directly assigning the object, we have written onto the parent `.prototype`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically `Object.create`'s first parameter is the prototype and second parameter is the property descriptor object. Hence when you are passing the *prototype* object to the `Object.create` alone, An *object* without any **own properties** would be created and the passed *object* would be assigned to the `__proto__` of the newly created object.

```
var x = {a:10};
var y = Object.create(x);
console.log(y); //{__proto__:{a:10}}
```

But when you are assigning the parent's prototype to the child's, simply the references are overlapped. And there will not be any structural change happen in the object.

Answer (score 1):

One difference I can think of is this:
assuming you have

```
c = new childObj()
p = new parentObj()
```

in both cases you'll have

```
c instanceof parentObj === true
```

but in the second case you'll also have

```
p instanceof childObj === true
```

whild in the first case you'll have

```
p instanceof childObj === false
```